# With a single entry visa, can I visit Ghana and return to India?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, india, residency, ghanaian-citizens

I am a student in India with a single entry student visa, a resident permit valid for one year. I am from Ghana. I want to go back to my country for two weeks and come back to India. Can I exit and return with the single entry visa and the resident permit which I have?

Answer (score 2):

No, you are not able to leave India and re-enter the country on your current visa. Your single-entry visa allows you into India one time only and, as you are already there, you won't be able to exit and return.

This is the usual practice, [**according to the Ministry of Home Affairs**](http://www.mha.nic.in/hindi/sites/upload_files/mhahindi/files/pdf/student_visa_faq.pdf),

> **How may ‘entries’ are allowed to foreign students?**
>
> Normally one entry. However, on bonafide reasons, a foreign student can apply for additional entries at:
>
> Visa Facilitation Centre
>   Foreigners Division
>   Ministry of Home Affairs
>   Jaisalmer House
>   26, Mansingh Road, New Delhi – 110003

And, for convenience, the directives from the [**Foreigners Division:**](http://mha1.nic.in/ForeigDiv/foreigners_division.htm)

> 1. Foreign nationals in India may require various services like Registration, Visa extension/conversion etc. For this purpose, various powers have been delegated to the FRROs/FROs [which are available on the weblink](http://mha1.nic.in/pdfs/ForeigD-PwrdlgtFRROs.pdf).
> 2. The foreign nationals are advised to visit the concerned jurisdictional  FRRO/FRO for such Visa related services.
> 3. If any service is required by foreign national which is not covered in the above mentioned delegated powers, even then the foreign national should visit the concerned jurisdictional FRRO/FRO and submit formal request for the service. The concerned FRRO/FRO will examine the request completely and if he/she prima facie agrees with the request of the foreigner, he/she will forward the application to the Ministry of Home Affairs for appropriate decision. If the concerned FRRO/FRO feels that the request of the Foreigner cannot be agreed to, he will straightaway advise the foreigner accordingly.
> 4. In case of any queries, Foreigners may contact Visa Support Center by email at visasupport@nic.in or on telephone numbers 011-22560198, 011-22560199

Comment: Seeing those rules and knowing Indian bureaucracy, I suspect processing time to get an additional entry in your one-year visa will be approximately 2 years...